# casperjs, error: cannot find module 'Path'

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

hi I am getting the error 'error: cannot find module 'Path' 
after running a basic example of casperjs.

```
$ casperjs sample.js
$ phantomjs --version    , returns 1.9.8
$ python --version       , returns Python 3.5.0
$ casperjs     , returns...
Error: cannot find module 'path'
phantomjs://bootstrap.js:289
phantomjs://boostrap.js:254 in require
bunch of other lines of code....
CasperJS versions 1.1.0beta
```

So it is even saying Casperjs is loaded! argggg. Been at this stupid thing for hours..................................
Please god someone, someone ........

Comment: Why do you want to run CasperJS without parameters? It has no REPL mode.

Comment: https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/898

Answer (score 0):

Missing this package in Linux

```
apt install fontconfig -y
```